# Submit form made up of partial views with jquery ajax in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, html-helper

The **goal**:
I'm moving my multiple view registration process to a single view made up of RenderPartial()'s. The reasoning behind this is that I want to reuse the partial views in my profile edit section after the account has been created.  I want my Register.aspx to behave in this manner:

```
<form id="myRegistrationForm">
    <div id="accountCreatePanel"><% Html.RenderPartial("AccountCreationPartial") %></div>
    <div id="personalInfoPanel"><% Html.RenderPartial("PersonalInfoPartial") %></div>
    <div id="goalsAccompsPanel"><% Html.RenderPartial("GoalsAndAccomplishmentsPartial") %></div>
    <div id="prefsPanel"><% Html.RenderPartial("PreferencesPartial") %></div>
</form>
<button id="nextButton" onclick="nextButtonClick();">Next >></button>
<button id="prevButton" onclick="prevButtonClick();"><< Previous</button>
```

All of these partials are strongly typed to RegistrationViewModel.cs.  I want to build up the view model piece by piece as I move through the registration process. Each of the render partials contain Html helpers for view model properties. I show/hide the panels with jQuery after each Ajax post.  I have gotten this working with the following methodology, but it's too cumbersome and verbose.

**Current solution that works but I know there must be a better way to achieve:**

Partials contain:

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.Property1)%>
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property1, new {ID = "property1text"%>
<%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.Property2)%>
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property2, new {ID = "property2text"%>
```

jQuery Ajax:

```
var jqxhr;
var jsonResponse;
 jqxhr = $.post('/Account/Register', {
                  Property1: $('#property1text').val(),
                  Property2: $('#property2text').val()
                }, function() {
                }, 'json').fail(function () {
                    alert('Account creation failed');
                }).done(function() {
                    jsonResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText);
                    if(!jsonResponse.CreationSuccess) alert('An account with this username already exists!');
                }).always(function () {

                });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Register(RegistrationViewModel viewModel)
{
    ....do some stuff...
    ....save viewModel properties to DB...
    return Json(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PersonalInfo(RegistrationViewModel viewModel)
{
    ...do some stuff...
    ...save viewModel properties to DB...
    return Json(viewModel);
}
```

**The problem with this solution:**
In my $.post() I have to physically type out every single property in the view model and get the val() of the form elements by ID.  I want to use **$('.form').serialize()** to pass the data as the view model arguments in the controller methods.

**Why I can't get $('.form').serialize() to work and what is happening:**
If I just use `<form id="myForm">`, the method attribute is GET and all the view model stuff comes back encoded in the URL (including username and password).  I encrypt the password in the DB, but not in the initial view model and I don't want it in the url.  When I change `<form method="POST">`, the browser actually displays the JSON object returned.  My current solution allows me to access returned properties of the view model client-side, asynchronously post without refresh, and I can complete the entire registration process quickly.  I just know that typing out everything in the view model in my jQuery is bad practice and will be tough to manage if/when my view model changes.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: You can wrap everything in a Html.BeginForm tag, and when submitting the given form, use FormCollection on your controller to obtain ALL the form elements and break them down on the server side. If you wish to do it, as you said, piece by piece, wrap different form elements on the partial view and submit. The key here is to use FormCollection on your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm going to give it a shot tomorrow and reply back with my findings...